# How did Landau & Lifshitz (Mechanics) get Equation 2.5?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, variational-calculus

I understood everything in Landau & Lifshitz's mechanics book until Equation 2.4,but I'm not sure what he means when he says "effecting the variation" and gets Equation 2.5.

Can anyone explain what he did when he "effected the variation"?

[image: Equations 2.4 and 2.5]

Comment: Not a duplicate question but the answers there probably answer your question as well:  [Why partial derivative in Lagrange is partial?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/772570/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is simply taking the variation with respect to two variables $L$ depends on.
$$
\delta (L(q,\dot{q},t))=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}\delta \dot{q}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\delta q+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\delta t
$$
If $L$ does not explicitly dependent on time, the third is zero, or the change in Lagrangian has gauge freedom over total derivative.

Comment: If you look at the unlabelled equation just before Equation (2.4), you can see that he is making a specific definition of $\delta$ that only varies $q$ and $\dot q$ without a change in $t$, and it is this that caused the third to be zero.